# Problemas com Array de Structs C/C++

Tags: array, c++, struct

Estou tentando fazer um programa que leia uma string e um int e armazene seus valores em um `struct` e depois imprima na tela, ainda estou aprendendo, perdão se for um erro muito óbvio.
Código:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct teste {
    int num;
    char str[16];
};

int main(){
    struct teste var[3];
    int i;
    
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        cin >> var[i].num;
        cin.getline(var[i].str, 16);
        //fgets(var[i].str, 15, stdin);
    }
    
    int j;
    
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        cout << endl << var[j].num << endl;
        cout << var[j].str << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tá ficando um `'\n'` no buffer depois que você lê o inteiro... Como a leitura seguinte é de uma linha inteira, ele acaba atrapalhando. Você pode fazer o seguinte pra ajeitar:

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        cin >> var[i].num;
        cin.ignore(); //ADICIONA ESSA LINHA AQUI
        cin.getline(var[i].str, 16);
        //fgets(var[i].str, 15, stdin);
    }
```